# Are there any memory/other overheads between returning after a `break` in a while loop and a `return` whilst inside a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

Are there any memory/other overheads between returning after a `break` in a while loop and a `return` whilst inside a while loop?

For example, in `test1` I can see that when the function returns, the variable `attempt` is deleted.

```
def test1(n):
    attempt = 0
    while True:
        value = random.random()
        if value < n:
            break

    return value
```

What about in `test2`? Is the variable `attempt` still deleted from memory when the function returns or is it kept in memory?

```
def test2(n):
    attempt = 0
    while True:
        value = random.random()
        if value < n:
            return value
```

What are the differences between writing code one way or another?

Comment: On CPython, the additional statement in the `break` version becomes an additional instruction. Apart from that, they’re completely equivalent.

Comment: In case of `break` on successful condition it will exit while loop and continue executing statements after while statement to till end. But in `return` it will come out from that method and no statements will be executed after the loop. Write a print statement after while loop to see difference.

Comment: You can prime the while loop and then get rid of the break all together; the additional benefit is that there is a random chance the while may not even be needed.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid what do you mean by prime the while loop? `while value < n: value=random.random()`?

Comment: @Ryan Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Fetch a test value first, then change the condition of the while to what you wrote. There is a chance you avoid one iteration of the loop.